# after installing itheme security plugin , unable to enter the admin page itself in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, godaddy-api

I tried to download ithemes security. however suddenly my website logged out and it is not getting opened anymore. This site can’t be reached - is the error message I am getting. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Open your FTP client, go to

```
www/wp-content/plugins/
```

Rename the folder named `better-wp-security` to `better-wp-security.bak`

Reload your website